# How to select requests by request_id only if all status is "no"?

Tags: mysql, sql

Results table:

```
id | request_id | status
 1 | 1          | Yes
 2 | 1          | Yes
 3 | 2          | Yes
 4 | 2          | No
 5 | 2          | Yes
 6 | 3          | No
 7 | 3          | No
 8 | 3          | No
```

How to select requests by request_id only if all status is "No", in this example "3" ?

Comment: Do you want 3 as a result? Or the last three records? Or the three IDs 6, 7, and 8? Or something else still?

Comment: three IDs  where is request_id same, and where status is same.

Comment: Specify the expected result-set table (formatted text here too.)

Comment: People, Thanks for great answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is to look up records with `NOT IN` (or `NOT EXISTS`):

```
select *
from mytable
where request_id not in (select request_id from mytable where status = 'Yes');
```

(In case there can be more statuses you want to exclude change `where status = 'Yes'` to `where status <> 'No'`.)

Comment: I would prefer `NOT EXISTS` since there can be NULL issues in `NOT IN` solution

Comment: @Radim Bača: Yes, I should have mentioned this. I prefer `NOT IN` for its simplicity, but for the rare case of nulls in a lookup one must be aware of the implications.

Comment: @RadimBača Thanks, because of that NULL issues I rub my hair this morning :)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . how to use NOT EXISTS in Inner Join?

Comment: With `NOT EXISTS`: `where not exists (select request_id from mytable other where other.status = 'Yes' and other.request_id = mytable.request_id)`. But well, you can just as well use `NOT IN` and exclude nulls: `where request_id not in (select request_id from mytable where status = 'Yes' and request_id is not null)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Danke!

Answer (score 3):

To get the request_ids who have all the rows with status = No you can use  aggregation

```
select request_id 
from demo
group by request_id 
having count(*)  = sum(status = 'No')
```

Here count(*) will get a count of all rows per request_id and `sum(status = 'No')` will count rows where status = 'No' per request_id, if both values are same this means all rows for a request have a status set to No

From your comments > To get all the rows not only request_id you can do a join using above

```
select a.*
from demo a
join (
   select request_id 
    from demo
    group by request_id 
    having count(*)  = sum(status = 'No') 
) b using(request_id)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DQG61105)

Comment: As to your second query: I would prefer a simple `where request_id in (select request_id ...)` over `join (select request_id ...) b using (request_id)`. That puts criteria where it belongs: in the `WHERE` clause :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are fine with a string of IDs:

```
select group_concat(id)
from mytable
group by request_id 
having max(status) = 'No';
```

('Yes' comes after 'No' in the alphabet, so if it's just these two values, you can use `MAX`.)

Comment: `max(status)` is a good way. It's not clear why the OP insists on having a string instead of a boolean. In the latter case, `max(bool_column)` is a logical _and_. Why is the `group_concat()` needed, though?

Comment: @underscore_d: It's an aggregation result. The OP has mentioned in a comment that they want to see record IDs.

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
           FROM my_table x
           LEFT
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.request_id = x.request_id
            AND y.status <> x.status
          WHERE x.status = 'No'
            AND y.id IS NULL;
```